# Find the common values in two different dataframes

Tags: r

I have two dataframes:

```
x1=rnorm(1000)
y1=rnorm(1000)
data1=data.frame(x1,y1)

x2=rnorm(700)
y2=rnorm(700)
data2=data.frame(x2,y2)
```

I wonder if I can search whether or not there are some points in common like :(x1i,y1i)=?(x2j,y2j) in these two data.frames.

Note that there are two different sizes

Thank you for help.

Comment: May be `intersect(data1, data2)` `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Thank you, but using this library in the example posted by Mr: @Ruthger Righart below, I have the next erreur, Erreur : not compatible

Comment: The column names were different. Try `intersect(data1, setNames(data2, names(data1)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may help. I created another example (your testdata did not give any common points):

```
x1=c(1.00,1.05,1.10,1.15,1.20)
y1=c(5.05,5.10,5.15,5.50,10.00)
data1=data.frame(x1,y1)

x2=c(1.05,2.00,1.20)
y2=c(5.10,5.50,10.00)
data2=data.frame(x2,y2)

data1$xy<-paste(x1,y1,sep=",")
data2$xy<-paste(x2,y2,sep=",")

data1$xy %in% data2$xy
```